# GTk Theme Class of Component

Tags: themes, gtk

I experienced a strange UI after installing Numix-Daily theme and I want to fix this.

[image: strange ui]

The color should not very dark (It should be grey).

My Question : What is the best way knowing what that (type or name) component is? Or what class that component implements?

So that I can change those unmatched color.

### Trial

On the file `gtk-widget.css` line 55, there a style of background.

```
    .background {
        background-color: @theme_bg_color;
        color: @theme_fg_color;
    }
```

I duplicate this to

```
    .background * {
        background-color: #f00;
        color: @theme_fg_color;
    }
```

and it is changed into red (But another component too, including text label).

Comment: Which PPA did you use for the 'numix-daily' gtk theme?

Comment: I install numix from market : `numix-gtk-theme` package. Is this outdated?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is from ppa:numix/ppa .

Comment: How about if you try setting your `gtk-theme` and `window-theme` to Numix. You can also try choosing a different icon theme. I think it's an issue with the different theme combinations.